# Multiple links in a column using wice_grid Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, wice-grid

How to add multiple links to a column in wice_grid

```
g.column do |task|
    link_to('Edit', edit_task_path(task))
    link_to('Show', task_path(task))
end
```

Only a link is shown, other link is not even shown. Rails version 4.0.2

Comment: So silly of me :(   answer is  g.column do |task|
    (link_to('Edit', edit_task_path(task))) +
    (link_to('Show', task_path(task)))
end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
g.column do |task|
    buffer = link_to('Edit', edit_task_path(task))
    buffer +=link_to('Show', task_path(task))
    raw buffer
end
```